# Which format does /dev/urandom output?

Tags: c, ubuntu

Hi can somebody tell me which format /dev/urandom outputs and How i can replicate the output manually?.

I am trying to remove the idea of randomness from the script i am writing/using and instead place an incrementing value in order like 1,2,3,4,5 etc...

Yet /dev/urandom does not output integers, i do not know which format the output is.
It looks like some kind of Hex/Binary

I think this is one way of using /dev/urandom

```
hexdump -C -n 8 /dev/random
```

However there maybe other ways. I am just trying to remove any randomness from my script and replace it with an incrementing value. So in order words instead of random values i want them all in order from the first possible in the /dev/urandom range to the last value in the /dev/urandom range.

Does anybody know how to do this?

-- update:
Using this line was completely a wrong approach in my original question

```
hexdump -C -n 8 /dev/random
```

because
/dev/urandom does actually output a integer normally not a binary/hex as i have now worked out.

Comment: When you say `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, what is the _type_ of these values?  `int`?  `char`?  Therein lies the key.

Comment: If you don't want random numbers, don't use /dev/urandom.  Just increment a variable though a range of values.

Comment: @PaulSanders please read my comments below to hookenz

Comment: @dbush yes exactly, yet the output is not numbers. So yes i need to know what the range is? and how to set the first value of the range, then loop through it to the last value in the range.

Comment: @PaulSanders i am not sure what the output type is of /dev/urandom that is what i am trying to work out. I dont think it is a int or a char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from /dev/urandom just gives you random bytes.  The code you mentioned in the comments reads 32 random bytes from /dev/urandom into a buffer.

If you don't want random values but instead a set of sequential values, write (for example) the values 1 to 32 in the 32 bytes, i.e:

```
for (i=0;i<32;i++) {
    seckey[i]=i+1; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no format. It's random bytes. Every byte is random.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how i can output the first possible byte in the whole  possible range

Comment: Like as you say its a random byte sequence. Do you know what the first possible byte output would be?

Comment: Read one byte.  It's 0 - 255 possible values.  If you read two bytes as a word you get 0 - 65536 values etc.

Comment: ok great, yet i am still confused to how it works. I will show you exactly what i am trying to do. if you look at this file at line 22 - https://github.com/nickfarrow/niceBit/blob/master/niceBit.c that is setting up the secKey value

Comment: however the script is generating random values, i am trying to change it to be just the first value of the range and remove /udev/random completely, do you know how to do this?

Comment: Reading between the lines, and given that `seckey` is of type `unsigned char [32]` long, you probably want to set the first byte to 0x01, the second to 0x02 and so on.  That's as good a way as any to get a deterministic (i.e. the opposite of random) value.  You can set the values in a loop.

Comment: @PaulSanders, thanks for your answer that makes sense. if i was to remove lines 22-28 on that github page. do you know how i would set seckey. would it be like this seckey = '0x01';

Comment: That code reads 32 random bytes from /dev/urandom.  So instead, write (for example) the values 1 to 32 in the 32 bytes, i.e. `for (i=0;i<32;i++) seckey[i]=i+1;`

Comment: @dbush i think you are right. I just changed it to this and i think it works (int secKey = 1;) i think for some reason i tried it earlier and it did not work, but it works fine now. Thanks

Comment: @dbush if you write it as your main answer instead of a comment i will accept it :)